# Loop to Create Option buttons in a Userform not working

Tags: vba, userform, radio-button

I need to create several option buttons in a Userform (each one for a array element).

Am I missing something here? Cause it returns an error..

```
DefaultTop = 60

For X = 0 To UBound(ArrPlants)

    Set Jonas(x) = SAPPlants.Controls.Add("Forms.optionbutton.1", Y, True)
      'Error on the above line ^^^

        With Jonas(x)
            .Top = DefaultTop + 20
            .Left = 12
            .Caption = ArrPlants(x)
        End With

 Next X
```

Error:

> Error Expected Sub or Procedure

Comment: _What line_ throws the error and _what is_ the error?

Comment: Line    
Set Jonas(x) = SAPPlants.Controls.Add("Forms.optionbutton.1", Y, True)

Error
Expected Sub or Procedure

Comment: How do you define `Jonas` in terms of variable type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `X` into the name of the OptionButton instead of using `Jonas(X)`.  Try the below and see how that works for you:

```
DefaultTop = 60

Dim Jonas as OptionButton

For X = 0 To UBound(ArrPlants)

    Set Jonas = SAPPlants.Controls.Add("Forms.optionbutton." & X + 1, Y, True)

        With Jonas
            .Top = DefaultTop + 20
            .Left = 12
            .Caption = ArrPlants(X)
        End With

 Next X
```

Further explanation [found here](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=125:userforms-in-excel-vba-userform-basics-add-controls-dynamically-at-run-time-using-the-add-method-userform-controls-a-snapshot&catid=79&Itemid=475):

[image]